# Reset 'root' user password in MySQL 5.7.x+

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.7

When I try to reset the MySQL root password on ubuntu system with the following command

```
update user set password=PASSWORD("newPwd") where User="root";
```

I see the error as,

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 5):

In MySQL 5.7, the password field in mysql.user table field was removed, now the field name is 'authentication_string'.

Follow these steps to reset 'root' password on Ubuntu

Stop the Service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Start MySQL without a password

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

**Note: the following command didn't work for me**
mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

Connect to MySQL

```
mysql -uroot
```

Set a new MySQL root password

```
mysql>  use mysql;

mysql>  update user set authentication_string=password('yourNewPwd') where user='root';

mysql>  flush privileges;

mysql>  quit
```

Re-start mysql service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Now, you can login with your updated password

```
mysql -u root -p
```